# c++ mqtt testing automatic_reconnect

Tags: c++11, mqtt, paho

I'm very new to mqtt c++ client.

i have a `mqtt::async_client` (documentation [here](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/cppdoc/classmqtt_1_1async__client.html)) client with [automatic reconnect options](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/cppdoc/classmqtt_1_1connect__options.html#ae5dd4f9ad611b79bfd847035cecd7b0b) that I want to  test but I am having difficulties in inducing a connection loss or connection interruptions.

Consider the following

```
   /* mqtt async client connecting to localhost with 
     port 1833 and is called "client_name"
   */
   mqtt::async_client cli("localhost", 1883, "client_name");
   const mqtt::connect_options conOp;

   /* set options to automatically reconnect after a connection loss(?)
      at every 10 seconds interval upto 40 seconds
   */
   conOpt.set_automatic_reconnect(10, 40);
  
   /* establish the connection */
   cli.connect(conOp);

   /* induce connection interruption for 42 seconds? */
   cli.interrupt_connection(42); //how to do this?
   
   bool isConnected = true;
   isConnected = cli->is_connected();

   std::cout << "Is the client connected ? "<< isConnected << "\n";
```

stdcout should be `false` since the connection could not be established.

Any suggestions will be really helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: It is sufficient to say: bool isConnected = cli->is_connected(); The type of cli->is_connected() will set the corresponding flag of the bool. If you are getting a true result then you've got a connection. Change the hostname for a moment and test it.

Comment: Kill the broker. That will interrupt the connection. Then when the broker comes back up it should reconnect.

Comment: i know the broker (which as far as I undersand) in my case is the `localhost``, has to be killed but I can't figure out how I  can do that in a unit test or while I'm working on my laptop.